# Import failed for jsonb field postgresql

Tags: postgresql, import, jsonb

I tried the below query to import data

```
COPY table_name(id, name, create_uid, create_date, write_uid, write_date)
FROM '/path/filename.csv'
DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER ENCODING 'UTF8' QUOTE '"' ESCAPE '''';
```

The name field data type is `JSONB`. I tried the below formats in my CSV file.

These 2 formats both produced the same error:

`"{"en_US": "Test record"}"` or `{"en_US": "Test record"}`

> Error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
> DETAIL:  Token "en_US" is invalid.

and this format produced a different error:

`'{"en_US": "Test record"}'`

> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
> DETAIL:  Token "'" is invalid.

How can I fix the above errors?

Answer (score 0):

Postgres uses `"` as escaping characters. Since importing from CSV file, postgres will escape the quotes.

Try something like,

```
"{""en_us"": ""Test record""}"
```

or

```
"{\"en_us\": \"Test record\"}"
```

Comment: Tried the above below ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "en_US" is invalid. or ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "\" is invalid.